# Cannot Install chkrootkit on Centos7

Tags: centos7

I cannot find the package chkrootkit 
the command:

`yum install chkrootkit`

returns: 
**No package chkrootkit available.**

I added the epel repository following this guide: https://www.tecmint.com/how-to-enable-epel-repository-for-rhel-centos-6-5/

but I didn't succeed.
How I can install it? I don't want to compile it.